# Why are there no new chapters of Naruto Gaiden?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

There have been only ten chapters and the manga has stopped being published. Why? What about the parts of the plot that have been left unexplained?

Comment: What parts of the plot are you referring to?

Comment: Ask the Mangaka?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring* is a sequel mini-series of the original Naruto manga, part of the Naruto Project. The Naruto Project is a special project to celebrate 15 years of the Naruto series.

The *Naruto Gaiden* acts as a prelude for *Boruto: Naruto the Movie*.

In Japanese literature, a gaiden (外伝) means side story or tale.

> The use of gaiden is commonly used in popular Japanese fiction to refer to a spin-off of a previously published work that is neither officially considered a sequel nor a prequel. However, some gaiden are retold stories in the perspective of a different character, similar to that of a flashback.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaiden)</sub>

Therefore gaiden is generally consists of only a few chapters.

The unexplained elements in the series might (most probably will) be elucidated in the upcoming series.